# Recover email address from special application of MD5 hash function

Tags: encryption, hash, md5

First, we segment the email address into 2-character strings.
Then, for every segment `s`, we compute the following hash J:

```
md5(md5(s) + s + md5(s))  [where + is the string concatenation operator].
```

Finally, we concatenate all hash strings J to form the long hash below.

For example: for an input of `helloworld@company.com`, we would compute:

```
md5(md5('he') + 'he' + md5('he')) +
md5(md5('ll') + 'll' + md5('ll')) +
md5(md5('ow') + 'ow' + md5('ow')) +
...
```

Long Hash:

```
f894e71e1551d1833a977df952d0cc9de44a1f9669fbf97d51309a2c6574d5eaa746cdeb9ee1a5df
c771d280d33e5672bf024973657c99bf80cb242d493d5bacc771b3b0b422d5c13595cf3e73cfb1df
91caedee7a6c5f3ce2c283564a39c52d3306d60cbc0e3e33d7ed01e780acb1ccd9174cfea4704eb2
33b0f06e52f6d5aba5a5a89e6122dd55f8efcf024961c1003d116007775d60a0d5781d2e35d747b5
dece2e0e3d79d272e40c8c66555f5525
```

How can I recover the email address from the hash? As I understand it, a "Hash" is a One Way Function. I can only compare it to another hash to see if they match or generate a Hash of the original text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it may be true *in general* that it is impractical to extract the original message from a hash, this clearly looks like an exercise with conditions carefully crafted to make it possible to break the "encryption".

---

Consider that the email address is broken up into two-character segments. If you limit yourself to just lowercase letters (26 letters + 2 symbols, `@` and `.`, there are only `28 * 28 = 784` possible two-letter combinations. Even if the emails have lowercase and uppercase letters and numbers, there are only `64 * 64 = 4096` combinations -- well within computational limits.

The thing to do is to pre-compute a [rainbow table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table), or table of all possible hash values in your search space. You could do this with a matrix:

```
 +----------------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
 |                a                 |                b                 |                c                       |             ...             |
 +----------------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
a| md5(md5('aa') + 'aa' + m5('aa')) | md5(md5('ba') + 'ba' + m5('ba')) | md5(md5('ca') + 'ca' + m5('ca'))       |             ...             |
 +----------------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
b| md5(md5('ab') + 'ab' + m5('ab')) | md5(md5('bb') + 'bb' + m5('bb')) | md5(md5('cb') + 'cb' + m5('cb'))       |             ...             |
 +----------------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
c| md5(md5('ac') + 'ac' + m5('ac')) | md5(md5('bc') + 'bc' + m5('bc')) | md5(md5('cc') + 'cc' + m5('cc'))       |             ...             |
 +----------------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
 |               ...                |               ...                |               ...                      |             ...             |
 +----------------------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

but then you would have to traverse the matrix each time to find a match -- slow!

An alternative is to use a dictionary with the key being the hash, and the value being the 'decoded' letters:

```
{ 
   md5(md5('aa') + 'aa' + md5('aa')): 'aa',
   md5(md5('ab') + 'ab' + md5('ab')): 'ab',
   md5(md5('ac') + 'ac' + md5('ac')): 'ac',
  ...
}
```

Either way, you will now have the hashes for all possible two-letter combinations. Now you process the input string. Since MD5 produces 32-character long hashes, break the input up into 32-character strings, and perform lookups against your table:

```
'f894e71e1551d1833a977df952d0cc9d' => 'he'
'e44a1f9669fbf97d51309a2c6574d5ea' => 'll'
...
```

Comment: Actually, not too bad. It is possible, unless you run into collisions, in which case you'd need to look over the data and do some guessing. Collisions would be apparent from the precomputed set. Still, it would not be a trivial task, as your assumption is that the email would be letters only - emails can have more symbols than that - numbers, underscores, plus signs and probably more I don't know of. Even then, there is nothing stopping the emails to have capital letters, too - it is possible that a user typed in NameLastname@mail.com, and the system just took it as it is and hashed it.

Comment: Basically, if you don't have much more information about the data set, you would be left with basically brute forcing it. Otherwise you would still do it but with just a more limited search space. One thing I did not notice until now is, however, that the long hash would actually give away how long an email is. Also, since you can expect many emails to end in .com or .co.uk or .de, etc common top level domains, you would be able to chop off the final 2-3 encrypted groups (4-6 characters) in a lot of cases as they'd be the same. In fact, email domains are another culprit (running out of chars)

Comment: @Vld Yeah, collisions can be found, an all possibilities printed out, still leaving you with just a small set of possible emails. As for brute forcing: in this case the force required is not so large at all. Even if you could have 100 possible characters in an email, the way the problem is set up, you still only need 10,000 entries in the lookup table -- a few seconds work, at worst.

Comment: So, for example `@gmail.com` would encrypted the same in any email which even number of symbols before the @ sign. If the number is odd, then `gmail.com` would be a recognisable string. Same with `@yahoo.com`, `@hotmail.com`, etc. - getting a list of common mail providers would drastically cut the number of emails you would need to crack. Assuming, you have a big list of those emails that need cracking. If it's a single one, then you'd at least restrict the choices probably.

Comment: @Vld Not limited to emails? 256 ascii characters would still be only 65536 rows in the table. This is peanuts compared to rainbow tables many gigabytes big used to break hashes. That is a much harder problem. This one is set up to be doable.

Comment: @Vld Yeah, good point: you could precompute domains and maybe other strings too -- like years: some people use their birth or other year in their address, ie. "SomeUnoriginalHandle2000@yahoo.com"

Comment: Yes, sorry - I did realise it. I was pretty much thought streming in my comments. It is possible, for the manner of encryption is vulnerable (leaving aside it's using MD5). Also, if you know that the email ends in `gmail.com`, then then obviously the previous encrypted group is `<character>@` so you only have `n` permutations rather than `n^2` for that pair and you do not need to add `@` to the `n` of all the rest of the precomputed. I do think it's possible now, yes.

Comment: @Vld - It is really trivial to setup such a rainbow table, today you can calculate about [8 Giga](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/#performance) MD5 hashes per second with common hardware. This would be a matter of milli seconds!

Comment: Thank you everyone for your input.

Answer (score 2):

Here is implementation of your question in python.

My Code:

```py
import hashlib, string

# lambda function for MD5
md5hashFunction = lambda data: hashlib.md5(data.encode()).hexdigest()

# lambda function for  md5(md5(data) + data + md5)
finalHash = lambda data: md5hashFunction(
    md5hashFunction(data) + data + md5hashFunction(data)
)


# All MD5 hashes are 32 char length size therefore we need dive 32 fixed parts
hashes = [
    "f894e71e1551d1833a977df952d0cc9d",
    "e44a1f9669fbf97d51309a2c6574d5ea",
    "a746cdeb9ee1a5dfc771d280d33e5672",
    "bf024973657c99bf80cb242d493d5bac",
    "c771b3b0b422d5c13595cf3e73cfb1df",
    "91caedee7a6c5f3ce2c283564a39c52d",
    "3306d60cbc0e3e33d7ed01e780acb1cc",
    "d9174cfea4704eb233b0f06e52f6d5ab",
    "a5a5a89e6122dd55f8efcf024961c100",
    "3d116007775d60a0d5781d2e35d747b5",
    "dece2e0e3d79d272e40c8c66555f5525",
]


# Enumurate all alphabet and extra characters for decryption => "_+.@"
alphabet = list(
    string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + "_+.@"
)

# Create python dictionary for map hashes to string
rainbowTable = {finalHash(x + y): x + y for x in alphabet for y in alphabet}
"""
rainbowTable

'31453dd786a8c6f6c7c8860d5fcea4be': 'aa',
 '857dce5bcf6b6b32bec281207b2dba80': 'ab',
 'e90d94b4b65ac19188fdae82acf7fbbc': 'ac',
 '67299b8cedc5eafea7dda1daf9356b54': 'ad',
 '40fca4e80bfc6e1faa2c4e2b7e0929f0': 'ae',
 'de48fc1bd98f5508c513f9947a514ce8': 'af',
 '4852089b1b43b45204907df0066c0edf': 'ag',
 'e1b82a5fe4fdcf73d034a0d5063ffe3f': 'ah',
         ...... Continues....

"""

# Search for matched hash and join to single string
print("".join([rainbowTable[hash] for hash in hashes]))


"""
f894e71e1551d1833a977df952d0cc9de44a1f9669fbf97d51309a2c6574d5eaa746cdeb9ee1a5df
c771d280d33e5672bf024973657c99bf80cb242d493d5bacc771b3b0b422d5c13595cf3e73cfb1df
91caedee7a6c5f3ce2c283564a39c52d3306d60cbc0e3e33d7ed01e780acb1ccd9174cfea4704eb2
33b0f06e52f6d5aba5a5a89e6122dd55f8efcf024961c1003d116007775d60a0d5781d2e35d747b5
dece2e0e3d79d272e40c8c66555f5525

"""


"""
Output ==> secret_jobs@anvato.com
"""
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do:

Step 1: Divide the hash string in 32 bit blocks

Step 2: find all possible combinations of 2 character strings from the list of strings which can be combination of alphabets, numbers and any special characters.

Step 3: generate MD5 hash code for that segment, concatenate it with plain text segment and same hash code and generate MD5 hash code again

Step 4: Compare the generates hash code with the existing hash code. If it matched save it in string buffer. Iterate this process till all the blocks are decoded. You will have your answer.

Comment: Thanks @helper. This is exactly what i was looking for. Will revert back if it indeed does work.